# mat-select can't select an option and don't call the respective method either

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, angular-material, angular-ngmodel

**batch.component.html**

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedOrgId" placeholder="Select Org" name="batch" 
                                (selectionChange)="orgChange(selectedOrgId)">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let option of loadedOrganization" [value]="option.org_id">{{ option.org_name }}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**batch.component.ts**

```
 orgChange(x): void {
    console.log('selection works=>', x);
}
```

I want to select an option and orgChange() method call simultaneously and pass the argument(org_id) through the method. But I can't find the problem here. Please help me out.

Comment: what is the issue? selectionChange not getting triggered when you change the value?

Comment: yes. selectionChange not triggering. When I select an option in dom there I can't select any and the method also not triggered. That's why in console.log() I can't find any result.

Comment: But in my case, that doesn't work. "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined" this error shows in console but code running as well. I haven't used any pipe here. What will be the problem you guess?  
@Chellappanவ

Comment: I found the problem. If I can solve I'll update it.